# Java EE 6 + GlassFish v3, anybody/business using this combination?

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

I'm searching on internet if any businesses developing projects using `Java EE6 + GlassFish v3`.

I discovered that LinkedIn uses `GlassFish and RoR(Ruby on Rails)`. By looking at its success I think GlassFish can be good choice for my next project. I've been using Tomcat and has little bit of knowledge but my next project I want to try something new.

So.. have anybody/businesses used Java EE6 + GlassFish v3?

If so could you share your opinion or experience like some difficulties or advantage?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why GlassFish? Why not JBoss?

Comment: I thought JBoss only offers Hibernate which is not web server, didn't know it offers web server.. But I want to stick with GlassFish.

Comment: JBoss AS is a full on Web Server. It was acquired by RedHat. The same company acquired Hibernate. In the end, both use Tomcat bundled with JEE goodies. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous folks that have stepped forward with their [stories](http://blogs.oracle.com/stories/) about using GlassFish.  Most have been with GlassFish Server 2.1 (which includes clustering and high availability features).

Some have used GlassFish Server 3 and Java EE 6.

Obviously, your milage may vary.

Full disclosure:  I work for Oracle on the integration of NetBeans and GlassFish, so I am biased.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, but I have to nitpick a bit:

> "By looking at its success I think
>   GlassFish can be good choice for my
>   next project"

Your reasoning is wrong. Just because they used this technology, that alone didn't make them sucessful. Glassfish is basically Tomcat with Java EE 6 features on top of it, and that combination can be very potent and used in a variety of situations.

It's what you want to build using these technologies matters.

Comment: And Hence why I asked, why not JBoss. Most of these webapp servers are "wrappers" to Tomcat with JEE features.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I mentioned GF because OP mentioned it. JBoss is a fine alternative.

Comment: @darioo: yes :) I knew someone will point that part of my statement. One reason I am asking is because NetBean comes with Java ee 6 and GlassFish so I was wondering if there are any reason for those combination to be superior than others.

Comment: @Masato-san, NetBeans, GlassFish, Java (all combined) are Sun (now Oracle) technologies. Hence it made perfect sense to bundle them together.

Comment: @Gentleman: Ahh... i see. I guess the way I think is wrong. (good stuff = bandled). It's good that i'm not in marketing business.

Comment: @masato-san, `(good stuff = bandled)`, not really....NetBeans, java, Glassfish are **all** owned by Oracle, so I don't think Oracle shipping its product with JBoss (which is owned by RedHat).